# Manage generated resources in Visual Studio C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

How can I better manager automatically generated resources in a C# project.  My current workflow is:

- Run the external program that re-generates new resources
- Go to the `Resource Manager` of the main program
- Delete all the resources
- Delete all the resources from the main program's `Resources` folder
    (otherwise I have to click a dialog box 200x when it says a file with that name exists)
- Copy newly generated resources into the `Resource Manager` of the main program w/ drag and drop

This is painful to do and very slow when I am constantly updating my generated resources.  Any tips about a better workflow would be greatly appreciated.